# How to use the javascript variable to jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to add a class after selecting the check box.`$I` values come from the database. `var a=user<?php echo $i; ?>;` This is displaying the proper value I am not able to pass to Jquery to add the class to `li` tag. even I tried double quote`("." +a)`.

Would you help me in this?

```
<style type="text/css">
.redBackground{
    background: red;
}
</style>

<ul class="peers">
<?php
    $i=0;
    while($userdata=$usertype1->fetch_assoc()){  
        $compare_u=$userdata['Id'];
    ?>
        <li class="user<?php echo $i; ?> lazyloadhide">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1">
        </li>
<?php $i++;}?>
</ul>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var a=user<?php echo $i; ?>;
     $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
        if ($('input[type=checkbox]').is(":checked")) {
             $('.' +a).addClass('redBackground');
        } else {
            $('.' +a).removeClass('redBackground');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you sure that the line `var a=user<?php echo $i; ?>;` stores the correct value to variable `a`??

Comment: Yes, Mr.Nirav, I am getting proper value.

Comment: String need quotes `var a='user<?php echo $i; ?>';`

Comment: @NiravMadariya, I have more than 15 li and depending upload my database users.

Comment: So this code is in a loop? If so you can simplify it by using a single jQuery event handler.

Comment: `var a` is clearly a syntax error ? Did you check your console

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, Yes, My code is in loop,

Comment: @AlivetoDie , Where should I add the click event in your code. In my code, I added the click event.If checkbox is checked then add class other wise remove class

Comment: @AlivetoDie, I am not talking about Edited code. Previously I added in my question and then I deleted my code and added your code.

Comment: @NarendraVerma  please post your original code, so that we can see that how's check-box is checked (click functionality of check-box)?

Comment: @AlivetoDie, Update my code. expect SQL query

Answer (score 1):

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
                       $(".user").each(function(){
           $(this).click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                 alert("checked");
                 $(this).addClass('redBackground');
            } else {
                 alert("unchecked");
                $(this).removeClass('redBackground');
            }
        });
    });
                            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input type="checkbox" class="user">A
    <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="user">B
```

Comment: Not able to check your output.

Comment: @NarendraVerma -- try now.